# Verify username and password using TWRequest

Tags: ios, twrequest

I have a doubt regarding `TWRequest`.

My requirement is that I need to enter the user name and password of Twitter in my application viewController, not in the settings of device.

Is it possible to verify the login credentials of Twitter in this manner?